# C# Linq to XML, remove parents and child when a sibling has data

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I dont no, if this make sense. But i have an pretty large XML file. Where i want to remove all the child and parent if its sibling meets and condition.

So everytime my node `<Periode> <gyldigTil>` has data, and is not empty, remove its parent and childs from my xml file. And everytime the node is empty keep parent childs and siblings.

this is my Linq C#

```
string file = Server.MapPath("ResponseCvrXML/" + "24347214" + ".xml");

string empty = " ";
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(file);
xd.Root.Element("hits").Elements("_source").ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
    {
        var name = x.Descendants("periode").First();
        if (name.Element("gyldigTil").Value == empty) {
        }
        else
        {
            x.Remove();
        }

    });


xd.Save(Server.MapPath("ResponseCvrXML/" + "24347214" + ".xml"));
```

and my XML file

```
 <Root>
  <took>24</took>
  <timed_out>false</timed_out>
  <_shards>
    <total>6</total>
    <successful>6</successful>
    <failed>0</failed>
  </_shards>
  <hits>
    <total>1</total>
    <max_score>17.372461</max_score>
    <hits>
      <_index>cvr-permanent-prod-20170205</_index>
      <_type>virksomhed</_type>
      <_id>4001115172</_id>
      <_score>17.372461</_score>
      <_source>
        <Vrvirksomhed>
      <cvrNummer>24347214</cvrNummer>
      <regNummer>
        <regnummer>A/S42018</regnummer>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>1999-10-18</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-02-10T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </regNummer>
      <brancheAnsvarskode>0</brancheAnsvarskode>
      <reklamebeskyttet>true</reklamebeskyttet>
      <navne>
        <navn>RIBO VINDUER A/S</navn>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>1992-03-27</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-03-19T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </navne>
      <navne>
        <navn>VELFAC INTERNATIONAL A/S</navn>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1992-03-28</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>1995-01-17</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-03-19T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </navne>

      <binavne>
        <navn>VELFAC INTERNATIONAL A/S</navn>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>1992-03-27</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-02-10T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </binavne>

      <binavne>
        <navn>VELFAC INTERNATIONAL A/S</navn>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil />
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-02-10T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </binavne>
      <beliggenhedsadresse>
        <landekode>DK</landekode>
        <fritekst />
        <vejkode>6375</vejkode>
        <kommune>
          <kommuneKode>667</kommuneKode>
          <kommuneNavn>RINGKØBING</kommuneNavn>
          <periode>
            <gyldigFra />
            <gyldigTil>2006-12-31</gyldigTil>
          </periode>
          <sidstOpdateret>1999-10-15T00:00:00+02:00</sidstOpdateret>
        </kommune>
        <husnummerFra>5</husnummerFra>

        <vejnavn>Ribovej</vejnavn>
        <bynavn>Rindum</bynavn>
        <postnummer>6950</postnummer>
        <postdistrikt>Ringkøbing</postdistrikt>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2006-12-31</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2013-11-22T22:40:23+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </beliggenhedsadresse>
      <beliggenhedsadresse>
        <landekode>DK</landekode>
        <fritekst />
        <vejkode>1605</vejkode>
        <kommune>
          <kommuneKode>760</kommuneKode>
          <kommuneNavn>RINGKØBING-SKJERN</kommuneNavn>
          <periode>
            <gyldigFra>2007-01-01</gyldigFra>
            <gyldigTil />
          </periode>
          <sidstOpdateret>2006-11-13T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
        </kommune>
        <husnummerFra>5</husnummerFra>
        <adresseId />
        <sidstValideret />
        <husnummerTil />
        <bogstavFra />
        <bogstavTil />
        <etage />
        <sidedoer />
        <conavn />
        <postboks />
        <vejnavn>Ribovej</vejnavn>
        <bynavn>Rindum</bynavn>
        <postnummer>6950</postnummer>
        <postdistrikt>Ringkøbing</postdistrikt>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2007-01-01</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2011-05-31</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2006-12-28T13:37:26+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </beliggenhedsadresse>
      <beliggenhedsadresse>
        <landekode>DK</landekode>
        <fritekst />
        <vejkode>1142</vejkode>
        <kommune>
          <kommuneKode>615</kommuneKode>
          <kommuneNavn>HORSENS</kommuneNavn>
          <periode>
            <gyldigFra>2007-01-01</gyldigFra>
            <gyldigTil />
          </periode>
          <sidstOpdateret>2006-11-13T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
        </kommune>
        <husnummerFra>23</husnummerFra>
        <adresseId>0b29b248-c194-4363-b687-c774c93c06f5</adresseId>
        <sidstValideret>2017-05-12T11:06:28.712+02:00</sidstValideret>
        <husnummerTil />
        <bogstavFra />
        <bogstavTil />
        <etage />
        <sidedoer />
        <conavn />
        <postboks />
        <vejnavn>Bygholm Søpark</vejnavn>
        <bynavn />
        <postnummer>8700</postnummer>
        <postdistrikt>Horsens</postdistrikt>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2011-06-01</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil />
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2013-06-26T19:32:22+02:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </beliggenhedsadresse>
      <telefonNummer>
        <kontaktoplysning>96755200</kontaktoplysning>
        <hemmelig>false</hemmelig>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2002-06-21</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil />
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2002-06-25T19:34:17+02:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </telefonNummer>
      <telefaxNummer>
        <kontaktoplysning>96755201</kontaktoplysning>
        <hemmelig>false</hemmelig>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2002-06-21</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2004-12-09</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2002-06-25T19:34:17+02:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </telefaxNummer>
      <elektroniskPost>
        <kontaktoplysning>velfac@velfac.dk</kontaktoplysning>
        <hemmelig>false</hemmelig>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2000-01-23</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2000-11-01</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2000-04-01T14:51:22+02:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </elektroniskPost>
      <elektroniskPost>
        <kontaktoplysning>velfac@velfac.dk</kontaktoplysning>
        <hemmelig>false</hemmelig>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2002-01-23</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2004-12-09</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2002-01-25T19:31:18+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </elektroniskPost>
      <obligatoriskEmail>
        <kontaktoplysning>salg@velfac.dk</kontaktoplysning>
        <hemmelig>true</hemmelig>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2015-11-30</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil />
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-11-30T15:45:31+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </obligatoriskEmail>
      <livsforloeb>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil />
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>1999-10-16T19:50:10+02:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </livsforloeb>
      <hovedbranche>
        <branchekode>203020</branchekode>
        <branchetekst>Fremstilling af dele af træ til bygninger</branchetekst>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2007-12-31</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2013-11-22T22:19:29+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </hovedbranche>
      <hovedbranche>
        <branchekode>162300</branchekode>
        <branchetekst>Fremstilling af bygningstømmer og snedkeriartikler i øvrigt</branchetekst>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2008-01-01</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2012-12-31</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-11-23T13:46:28+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </hovedbranche>
      <hovedbranche>
        <branchekode>467310</branchekode>
        <branchetekst>Engroshandel med træ, trælast og byggematerialer</branchetekst>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2013-01-01</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil />
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-11-23T13:46:28+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </hovedbranche>
      <bibranche1>
        <branchekode>515310</branchekode>
        <branchetekst>Engroshandel med træ, trælast og byggematerialer</branchetekst>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2006-12-31</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2013-11-22T22:19:29+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </bibranche1>
      <bibranche1>
        <branchekode>682040</branchekode>
        <branchetekst>Udlejning af erhvervsejendomme</branchetekst>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>2014-01-01</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil>2014-01-01</gyldigTil>
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-11-20T15:14:41+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </bibranche1>
      <virksomhedsstatus>
        <status>NORMAL</status>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil />
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2015-02-10T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </virksomhedsstatus>
      <virksomhedsform>
        <virksomhedsformkode>60</virksomhedsformkode>
        <kortBeskrivelse>A/S</kortBeskrivelse>
        <langBeskrivelse>Aktieselskab</langBeskrivelse>
        <ansvarligDataleverandoer>E&amp;S</ansvarligDataleverandoer>
        <periode>
          <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
          <gyldigTil />
        </periode>
        <sidstOpdateret>2013-11-22T21:57:52+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
      </virksomhedsform>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? I would point out there's no element `hits` in the XML you've included, nor are there any `gyldigTil` elements containing a single space.

Comment: I simplified the xml, Because its so large. The problem i want to check if gyldigTil is empty or not. And only keep the parent elements Where gyldigTil  is empty.

Comment: Why are people always `.ToList()`ing things without any reason?

Comment: What if you use `string.Empty` instead of `" "` (which is a string containing one blank, not empty).

Comment: The problem isn't what you want to do. We know what you want to do. And we can see that you've tried to do it. What is the problem with the code you have tried? You need to provide a [mcve] (not your entire XML) and clearly explain the *problem* with the example code you provide.

Comment: the problem is, it does gives any error. But nothing happens. I have just added the root of the xml file.

Comment: Your top-level `hits` element doesn't have a `_source`  element - there's another `hits` element in between them, and you're not looking for that. So `xd.Root.Element("hits").Elements("_source")` returns an empty sequence.

Comment: you were right, now something happens, it removed the entire _source section, and i only wants to remove the child element where gyldigTil meets condition

Answer (score 0):

More LINQish way with a changed check for the emptyness.
Does this one do what you want?

```
xd.Descendants("hits")
.Elements("_source")
.Descendants("periode")
.Elements("gyldigTil")
.Where(gt => gt.Nodes().Any())
.Select(gt => gt.Parent.Parent)
.Remove()
```

Comment: it does not work perhaps my roots are wrong, it does not make any error

Comment: i just added the root of my xml file, i think perhaps i am doing it wrong.

Comment: You don't need the variable here - you can just call the `Remove` extension method: `xd.Root.Element(...).Elements(...).etc.Remove();`

Comment: tried out the code, but it removes to much. it removes the entire hits/_source  section. And i only wants to remove the parent, containg my child node.  so if  <binavne>
            <navn>VELFAC INTERNATIONAL A/S</navn>
            <periode>
              <gyldigFra>1969-09-29</gyldigFra>
              <gyldigTil >1999-09-19</gyldigTil>
            </periode>
            <sidstOpdateret>2015-02-10T00:00:00+01:00</sidstOpdateret>
          </binavne>      gyldigTil  Has value then remove its parent "binavne"

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks, wasn't aware of it's existence. It even snapshots, which my code failed to.

Comment: Edited my answer. Seems to do what you want now. Right?

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my hero :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Welcome to accept/upvote (not begging for it, but less experienced visitors sometimes don't know about it, so I'm telling)